# bash 'fold' screws up encoding in emacs

Tags: bash, emacs

Reading lines from a 'somefile' and writing them to 'sample.org' file.

`echo "$line" 1>>sample.org` gives correct result, which is '*Субъективная оценка (от 1 до 5)*: 4 - отличный, понятный и богатый вкусом ..' (russian letters)

`echo "$line" | fold -w 160 1>>sample.org` gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEsL3.png), which is technically correct if you copypaste it anywhere outside emacs. But still. Why using `fold` results in my emacs displaying 'sample.org' buffer in 'RAW-TEXT' instead of 'UTF-8'

To reproduce it create 2 files in same directory - test.sh, which will contain

```sh
cat 'test.org' |
  while read -r line; do
    # echo "$line" 1>'newfile.org' # works fine
    # line below writes those weird chars to the output file
    echo "$line" | fold -w 160 1>'newfile.org'
  done
```

and `test.org` file, which will contain just 'Среднеферментированный среднепрожаренный улун полусферической скрутки. Содержание ГАМК 200мг/100г.'

Run the script with `bash text.sh` and hopefully you will see the problem in the output file `newfile.org`

Comment: The image looks like the first line is raw, while the other two are in some unspecified 8-bit (?) encoding. I don't think we can tell what happened here without access to the input file and whatever else you can supply to provide us with a proper [mre].

Comment: @tripleee added reproduce steps

Comment: Thanks for the update. (That's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't repro this on MacOS, but in an Ubuntu Docker image, it happens because `fold` inserts a newline in the middle of a UTF-8 multibyte sequence.

```
root@ef177a152b15:/# cat test.org 
Среднеферментированный среднепрожаренный улун полусферической скрутки. Содержание ГАМК 200мг/100г.
root@ef177a152b15:/# fold -w 160 test.org >newfile.org
root@ef177a152b15:/# cat newfile.org 
Среднеферментированный среднепрожаренный улун полусферической скрутки. Содержание Г?
?МК 200мг/100г.
root@ef177a152b15:/# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

(Perhaps also notice that your demo script can be reduced to a one-liner.)

I would have thought that GNU `fold` is locale-aware, but that you have to configure a UTF-8 locale for the support to be active; but that changes nothing for me.

```
root@ef177a152b15:/# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
root@ef177a152b15:/# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 fold -w 160 test.org 
Среднеферментированный среднепрожаренный улун полусферической скрутки. Содержание Г?
?МК 200мг/100г.
```

Under these circumstances, the best I can offer is to replace `fold` with a simple replacement.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sys import argv

maxlen = int(argv.pop(1))

for file in argv[1:]:
    with open(file) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            while len(line) > maxlen:
                print(line[0:maxlen])
                line = line[maxlen:]
            print(line, end='')
```

For simplicity, this doesn't have any option processing; just pass in the maximum length as the first argument.

(Python 3 uses UTF-8 throughout on any sane platform. Unfortunately, that excludes Windows; but I am restating the obvious.)

Bash, of course, is entirely innocent here; the shell does not control external utilities like `fold`. (But not much help, either; `echo "${tekst:48:64}"` produces similar mojibake.)

Comment: I tried `locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8` and activating that locale, but that didn't help at all, either. I was hoping Awk might be UTF-8 clean, but alas, no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where that images comes from, however `fold` and `coreutils` in general, as well as huge number of other common cli utils, can only be safely used with inputs consisting of symbols from Posix Portable Character Set and not with multibyte UTF-8, regardless of what bullshit websites such as utf8everywhere.org state. `fold` suffers from the common problem - it assumes that each symbol occupies just a singe `char` causing multibyte UTF-8 input to be corrupted when it splits the lines.

Comment: For me, `fold` under a UTF-8 locale works just fine.

Comment: @choroba For me it does not. At least on Ubuntu 18.04. And even if it worked it is wrong to assume that something that depends on environment will always work without explicitly checking on each invocation whether environment is in appropriate state.

Comment: @user7860670, the images come from emacs buffer, which i open after the output has been written there. Buffer is displayed in RAW-TEXT instead of UTF-8. But i got the reason why it's doing it, yes.